# Using a slick slider with even number of slides to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm using a slick slider on Center Mode where the number of slidesToShow is an even number.
The requirement i have is for the active slides to be at opacity 1 and the rest at opacity 0.5.
Slick js has a slick-active class that is applied to it automatically. Unfortunately the number of slides being even makes the implenetation wrong.
[image]

As seen in the picture the first half inactive slide on the left is at half opacity. I want the same for the 5th slide with 'slide-active' class. Somehow the nth-child and last-child selectors aren't working as I assumed.

What could be a work around?

Comment: could you please share your code ?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/golaxasote/edit?html,css,js

Answer (score 1):

try adding reduced opacity to slick-slide class and then apply full opacity to active slides.

```
  $('.accom-slider').slick({
    centerMode: true,
   slidesToShow: 3
   });
```

Comment: Added the code as you said.
The slide-cloned are only present in the slick-slider before the class slick-center. Hence only half are showing up at 1 opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I've made something like this for my use, hope it can help:
http://test.woolet.co/slick-slider-centered/

```
    $('.center').slick({
      speed: 500,
      arrows: false,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '0px',
      slidesToShow: 3
    });
```

Comment: Hey thanks Pawel, but just that my question is regarding emulating this effect when the number of slidesToShow are even. Thanks for the comment.